# Parse JSON Response to a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, json, parsing, response

I'm writing a code needs he YouTube API request. And now, I need to store the JSON response in a Python dictionary. To be able to change the title of a video in YouTube.

`

```
import json
import requests

videoID = "string"
API_KEY = "string"
response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoID + "&key=" + API_KEY + "&part=statistics")

print(response.json())
```

`

**So this is what I tried so far, and now I need to store my response *JSON* variable in a *Python* dictionary**

And then tried this:

```
json.loads(response)
```

The OUPUT:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-ad7863f2e12c> in <module>
      7 response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoID + "&key=" + API_KEY + "&part=statistics")
      8 
----> 9 json.loads(response)
     10 print(response.json())

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    339     else:
    340         if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):
--> 341             raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
    342                             f'not {s.__class__.__name__}')
    343         s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response
```

Comment: use   `json.loads(response)`

Comment: The error message is quite clear - `json.loads` expects a string. Why are you doing that anyway? The `Response` object has a `json` method on it, which you were using in the original code. Why did you change that?

Comment: `mydict = json.loads(response.text)
print(mydict)`

Comment: @Mohamedchouai that isn't necessary - `response.json()` already returns the dictionary.